# C, Imprimir y guardar cadena de caracteres

Tags: c

Es un programa simple, lo intente con en vez de palabras letras y funciono, pero quise jugar un poco pero no se como hacerle para las palabras, para una letra si me funciona.

Me tira este error:
warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]|

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

char opc[10];

printf("De que color es el cielo?: ");
printf("\nA. Azul");
printf("\nB. Rojo");
printf("\nC. verde");
printf("\nD. morado\n");
scanf("%s", opc);

if(*opc=='azul'){
    printf("El resultado es correcto");
}else{
    printf("El resultado incorrecto");
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se queja de que la *comilla-simple* `'` se usa para indicar **caracteres**, no cadenas de mas de 1 carácter.

Las cadenas en *C* no se comparan así; tienes que usar la función `strcmp( )`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ){
  char opc[10];

  printf( "De que color es el cielo?: " );
  printf( "\nA. Azul" );
  printf( "\nB. Rojo" );
  printf( "\nC. verde" );
  printf( "\nD. morado\n" );
  scanf( "%s", opc );

  if( !strcmp( "azul", opc ) ) {
    printf( "El resultado es correcto" );
  } else {
    printf( "El resultado incorrecto" );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok ya esta gracias, aun no se mucho se aprecia.